# Trigonometric integration $ \int \sqrt{1-\sin2x}dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I could not figure out how to solve this problem. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this: $$ \int \sqrt{1-\sin2x}dx$$

Comment: See also [How to integrate $\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/785271) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B1-%5Csin2x%7D%20dx%24&p=1).