# A doubt in indefinite Integration

Tags: integration

> I need to find
>   $$
> \int \sqrt{1-\sin (2x)} dx
> $$

I have a doubt in this: the square root is equal to $|\sin x-\cos x|$ can we integrate this without knowing the limits?

Comment: Are you asking to solve this integral: $\int \sqrt{1 - \sin 2x}$?

Comment: Here is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: Yes , we need to evaluate this.

Comment: Does this answers to your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785271/how-to-integrate-sqrt1-sin-2x

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\sin x - \cos x) $ is negative when $x \in [0, \pi/4]$ and
positive when $x \in[\pi/4,\pi]$. So it matters, what  is the interval of $x$ is. Otherwise, the answer will be ambiguous by $(\pm)$.

Comment: If you think of any function $f(x)$, it is generally true that "it matters what value(s) $x$ takes" --  different $x$'s produce different $f(x)$'s...

Comment: Yes, you have a point I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If you would like to compute $\int |x| dx$, then, since
$$
|x| = \begin{cases} x, & x \ge 0 \\ -x, & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
we can certainly claim that up to a constant,
$$
\int |x| dx
 = \begin{cases} \int x dx, & x \ge 0 \\ \int (-x) dx, & x < 0 \end{cases}
 = \begin{cases} x^2/2, & x \ge 0 \\ -x^2/2, & x < 0 \end{cases}
 = \mathrm{sgn}(x) \frac{x^2}{2},
$$
which is a perfectly valid function.

Comment: But the sign of sinx-cosx changes periodically

Comment: @ARMY1729 correct, so instead of $x \ge 0$, you will condition on $\sin x \ge \cos x$ (which you can either express in terms of tangents, or just list the corresponding values of $x$).

Comment: So without limits it's not easily evaluated

Comment: @ARMY1729 not sure what *easily* means in this context. You will get a function with 2 branches, does not sound so hard to me

Comment: I mean relatively hard,sorry.